# Link static libs (.a) into exe with mingw

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, static-libraries, qmake

I'm currently trying to play around with OpenCV but I ran into a bit of trouble.. 
I use the qt ide with mingw to compile my applications.

My code looks like this:

```
#include “highgui.h”

int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{
    IplImage* img1 = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
    cvNamedWindow( “Example”, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( “Example”, img1 );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img1 );
    cvDestroyWindow( “Example” );
    return(0);
}
```

And this is in my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/OpenCV2MinGWBuild/install/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/OpenCV2MinGWBuild/install/include/opencv/"
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/OpenCV2MinGWBuild/install/include/opencv2/"
LIBS += -L"E:/OpenCV2MinGWBuild/install/lib/" -lopencv_calib3d231.dll -lopencv_contrib231.dll -lopencv_core231.dll
```

The libraries are .a-s(the dll is in the name part of the lib, it's not an extension).. I know that .a libraries are linux specific but mingw sould be able to use them right?

I built the OpenCV libraries with mingw, but I can't get them to link to my Qt application.. 
MinGW can see the header files just fine, but not the libraries.
I always get "undefined reference to `cvShowImage'", "undefined reference to`cvNamedWindow'"  (etc)errors..

Any help is appreciated!
Thnx!

Comment: These .a files are Windows or Linux libraries?

Comment: They are compiled with mingw under windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dll.a are not static library files they are stubs for the dynamic linked `.dll` - you need to rebuild OpenCv to use static libs `.lib` and link those directly with your code

Comment: @Martin care to point out how to rebuild them that way? Is it an option in CMake?

Comment: @IvoFlipse, never needed to, but apparently just uncheck 'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS' in cmake. see http://www.shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/